# MVC pass query strings

Tags: model-view-controller, rest

I am new to Microsoft.MVC, so sorry if this is a silly question.

I have created a very simple forum, and I am now trying to create some tag functionality to it.

I have a controller where the index retrieves the last 10 forum threads. I would like to pass a query string, or something a-like with the Id to the supplied tag to the forum, so I thereby can get the forum threads, which e.g. have the tag 'ASP.NET'.

If it was a regular webforms project I would simply supply a query string with the tag id, to the index page, and then retrieve the forum threads with the tag, but isn't there a smarter way to do it in MVC.NET?

The reason why I ask, is it seems like a step backwards from REST-urls, to suddenly use 'regular' query strings?

Comment: You mean like /tags/asp.net?forum=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you define your action (like you probably already did), and add the parameters like you need them:

```
public ActionResult Forum(string tag, int page)
{
    // do your thing
    // ...

    return View();
}
```

Then, in your Global.asax.cs, you can add a route that handles the parameters like you want them.

```
routes.MapRoute("Forum", "Forum/{tag}/{page}", new {controller = "Home", action = Forum"});
```

This will cause the Forum action to trigger on the HomeController when you go to the http://yourhost/Forum link.  If you then click have a link like this http://yourhost/Forum/asp.net/1 Then "asp.net" will passed into the tag parameter, and 1 will be passed onto the page parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ActionLink html helper.  Assuming you have a forums controller and index page, to get a link to /forums/index/1?tag=asp.net you can do:

```
Html.ActionLink("ASP.NET", "index", new { id = 1, tag = "asp.net"})
```

Comment: I am sorry if my question wasn't so clear, but I was asking if there was another way to pass parameters than to use query strings i MVC.NET, since it in my opinion destroys all the benefits of REST.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought I did answer your question. Before you go to far with routes, consider this example I saw in a production system: /filter/2010/1/1/2010/1/31. That is route abuse. Why not do /filter?start=2010/1/1&end=2010/1/31. It's easier to read, debug, understand, and maintain.